# In App Purchase NOT using Google Play Services

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I plan on uploading my game to my personal website and prefer to not use Google Play or other hosting sites. I'm completely inexperienced outside of the hosting sites. I know how to create an itemID for in app purchases using GooglePlay, however, how would I go about doing the transactions without all of that? I cannot find anything about the steps to take.

What I need to know:

1. How to link the transaction to my account (PayPal or checking).
2. How to reward the player accordingly (I prefer to use a Singleton pattern).

My setup:

1. I have a pause menu with a button to open the store menu.
2. My items are displayed with a "buy" button next to each item.
3. The "buy" button has OnClickEvent() related to public static functions for each.

   ```
   // public class InAppPurchase

   public static InAppPurchase inst;
   private void Awake()
   {
    if(instance != null)
   {
       Destroy(gameObject);
   }
   else
   {
       instance = this;
       DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
   }
    }// End of Awake()
   public static void BuyAdFreeVersion()
    {
       // Need to know how to charge the client here
       // Don't know any code that doesn't require GooglePlay ID
       // How does this work exactly?
    }


    // public class InAppButtons

    public void RemoveAdsButton() // This will be added to the button itself
    {
        InAppPurchase.inst.BuyAdFreeVersion();
    }
   ```

Comment: This is way too broad for SO. Even small part which is roughly "what payment provider should I use to handle in-app purchases in Unity3d app running on Android" is off-topic as search for recommendations. Side note: you may want to check what payment providers are allowed on platform you are using - i.e. Apple's store apps have very little choice if they are to stay compliant...

Comment: I'm using the 2D version Android platform. I've been searching for something relevant but I find nothing of use. I don't know how to add a Paypal to charge for the transaction. How would that work? I honestly didn't think this was "too broad" of a question; it's pretty straight forward. Perhaps you could provide me with some of these useful links you mention to help? @AlexeiLevenkov

Comment: @AntonioTorro it is way too broad as there are numerous of ways it can be handled.    There is not enough information in here, to bring you to a good solution that isn't highly opinion based.

Comment: Are you currently registered with any merchanting services?

Comment: @Eddge- I have a merchant account for my website which is set up to receive payment through PayPal. I have a GooglePlay merchant account as well. I've published a game before on GooglePlay, Gamejolt, and Itch.io. However, I am only planning on uploading to my website. The code tat I know I can upload to GooglePlay with no problem, but I want to start making my website the exclusive place. Unfortunately, I don't know how the IAP works without using the Google Merchant. I can't seem to find any links that explain exactly how this works.

Comment: @Eddge - I'm open to some opinion based answers. I just need a good idea of where to start. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: I'm also not opposed to adding more content to the opening post. I don't know what information is required though. Let me know! Thanks!